# How to connect URL in Virtual Machine from Android browser

Tags: android, virtual-machine, weblogic

All

Need suggestion.

I have installed Weblogic in VM (OS: Windows server 2008 Datacenter).

Weblogic console URL is

http://hostname:7001/console or

http://IPAddress:7001/console

Base machine is Windows 10 (Host: ABC)

I can access above URL from base machine but I could not able to access same URL from

1. Other computers and
2. Android browser.

provided the same network and firewall is OFF.

[image: Image Representation]

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question is opinion based and does belong here. Did you try to perform basic troubleshoot such as ping, telnet. what are the results ?

Comment: Yes I tried ping but no luck.
Got Unknown HOST/IP

Comment: check the firewalls on both machines. First you need to make the machine available to other computers

Comment: Yes firewalls are turned OFF in both machines still no luck

Comment: go through this https://serverfault.com/questions/18506/what-to-check-if-pinging-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved...

In Virtual Machine Workstation, choose edit option --> Network Adapter --> Custom: Specific virtual network.
[image: Solution]